# #WhyMagento? - Here are the answers from the Community

Tags: discussion, extensions

As part of a Magento extension developer company (called, Prisync), I am getting more and more into the community every day, and as I engage with all the folks from all around the world, I hear common stories around how they all get into the Magento community.

Seeing all those vibrant and inspiring stories, I decided to ask them a simple question: #WhyMagento? and compiled some of the answers on the blog post below:
https://blog.prisync.com/whymagento-community-answers-back/

The piece is planned to be a dynamic one so I am quite eager to receive more and more answers from you to enrich the content and populate as many stories as possible.

So, dear Magento StackExchange community, #WhyMagento?
How did you all get started with it and of course, why?

Comment: Hi Burc, welcome to Magento SE! The type of question that you have posted is not suitable for the StackExchange Q&A platform, please read https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. I have voted to move your question to the Magento SE Meta site. Maybe it will be accepted there...

Comment: Thanks a lot @7ochem!